# Objective C Subclass of Superclass initialisation

Tags: objective-c, inheritance

I want to check if the following implementation of a subclass is correct in objective C.

First code a wrote for the parent superclass:

```
 #import "Employee.h"

    @implementation Employee

   -(id)init
   {
    return [self initEmployee:(NSString *)@"" withId:(NSString *)0];
   }

   -(id)initEmployee:(NSString *)theName withId:(NSString *)theId 
   {
       self = [super init];
       if (self) {
            _name = theName;
            _EmpId = theId;
       }
       return self;
    }

    @end
```

Then the subclass.

```
#import "FullTimeEmp.h"

@implementation FullTimeEmp

-(id)init
{
    return [self initEmployee:(NSString *)@""
                       withId:(NSString *)@""
                    andSalary:(NSNumber *)0
                    withBonus:(NSNumber *)0];
}

-(id)initEmployee:(NSString *)theName
           withId:(NSString *)theId
        andSalary:(NSNumber *)theSalary
        withBonus:(NSNumber *)theBonus
{
    self = [super initEmployee:(NSString *)theName withId:(NSString *)theId];
    if (self) {
        self.salary = theSalary;
        self.bonus = theBonus;
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

This runs fine but I have not been able to confirm that this is the correct way to do it, using:

self = [super initEmployee:(NSString *)theName withId:(NSString *)theId];

In the subclass to inherit the superclass part (Name and ID) and then the subclass part to specify the subclass additions (Salary and Bonus) to make up the Full Time Employee object.

I have read all about the reason we use self = [super init] but have been hard pressed to find good examples of how the initialization in subclasses is coded in any of the books I have or online.

Comment: **Why,** oh why all those superfluous, ugly, unreadable, incorrect casts? :((((

Comment: Please read [*Coding Guidelines for Cocoa: Naming Methods*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingMethods.html).  Better names are `initWithName:employeeId:` and `initWithName:employeeId:salary:bonus:`.

Answer (score 0):

You've got the right idea as far as initialization goes. You basically just have to properly initialize the superclass in some way. You don't *have* to do it exactly this way where your subclass is basically your superclass with some additional members, but in this case it seems appropriate. You might have a subclass where, for instance, `theId` or some other field will always be the same value for that subclass, in which case you wouldn't need to pass a value for it to the initializer of the subclass. As long as you initialize the superclass in whatever way is most appropriate for your situation, you should be good.

However, you seem to be confusing the syntax for method signatures and method calls, or sending messages. This:

```
self = [super initEmployee:(NSString *)theName withId:(NSString *)theId];
```

and similar should just be this:

```
self = [super initEmployee:theName withId:theId];
```

When you're defining a method, you need those `(NSString *)` things to tell the compiler what type each of your arguments is, but when you're calling the method/sending a message you already have an object for the argument which already has a known type, so you don't need it. What you're actually accomplishing here is *casting* an `NSString *` to an `NSString *`, which is obviously superfluous.

EDIT: As Grzegorz mentions, in general it's better to access your properties directly through their instance variables in your initialization methods, i.e. instead of:

```
self.salary = theSalary;
```

instead do:

```
_salary = theSalary;
```

presuming you haven't synthesized it under a different name. One good reason is because a subclass could override the setter method for the property, which could lead to very unpredictable behavior. In general, sending messages to `self` while in a partially constructed state is to be avoided, since doing so can have side-effects. Obviously if you're setting a property defined by a superclass and you don't have access to the instance variable, or you're using lazy initialization, you don't have much choice but to use the setter (other than to just not initialize it here), but that's not what you have in this example.

EDIT 2: Also, a couple of points with this:

```
-(id)init
{
    return [self initEmployee:(NSString *)@""
                       withId:(NSString *)@""
                    andSalary:(NSNumber *)0
                    withBonus:(NSNumber *)0];
}
```

First, you needn't feel compelled to provide a straight `init` method if it doesn't make sense to have default values for these things. If you're OK having an employee with no name and no ID, then fine, but if it only makes sense for you to initialize one of your classes with actual data, then don't feel bad about not overriding `init`, or even about throwing an exception from it if you really want to stop people using it.

Second, an `NSNumber` is an object, so when you try to assign a straight `0` to it, it's equivalent to setting the pointer to `nil` and not creating an object at all, which is probably not what you want here. To actually create `NSNumber`s with the value zero, you'd want to use literals in the same way you do for `NSString`, as so (also here removing the casts):

```
-(id)init
{
    return [self initEmployee:@""
                       withId:@""
                    andSalary:@0
                    withBonus:@0];
}
```

or just use a regular `int` instead of an `NSNumber` if you don't need them to be objects at all.

Comment: add a comment about not using self. and straight _var - it can lead to not retaining parameters - i believe he is now aware of that

Comment: Thanks @PaulGriffiths & GrzegorzKrukowski for the very thorough response to my coding. All very well explained and clear in my mind now. As I mentioned I was finding it difficult to find some concrete examples of how to this properly.

Answer (score 0):

As an update to my question in the OP and to help others who may have the same confusion here is my code re-ritten as per the advice given:

```
#import "Employee.h"

@implementation Employee

-(id)initEmployee:(NSString *)theName withId:(NSString *)theId 
{
  self = [super init];
  if (self) {
    _name = theName;
    _EmpId = theId;
  }
return self;
}

@end
```

And

```
#import "FullTimeEmp.h"

@implementation FullTimeEmp

-(id)initEmployee:(NSString *)theName
           withId:(NSString *)theId
        andSalary:(NSNumber *)theSalary
        withBonus:(NSNumber *)theBonus
{
    self = [super initEmployee:theName withId:theId];
    if (self) {
        _salary = theSalary;
        _bonus = theBonus;
    }
return self;
}

-(NSNumber *)calcPay
{
   NSNumber *pay;
   pay = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:([self.salary floatValue] + [self.bonus floatValue])];
   return pay;
}


@end
```